# Cron Expression : First Friday after the third Monday of the month

Tags: cron

I'm looking for a CRON expression which can find the first Friday after the third Monday of the month.

It's easy to find the third Monday (5 9 * * 1 [ `date +\%d` -le 7 ]) but i want the first friday after.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With more research, I find a solution but i'm not proud of this :

0 1 19-25 * 5

Hope, it will help.

Thanks